# C# invoke forms asynchronously

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding an addin for Excel and have some pop up Forms that come up asynchronously on top of all windows near the icon tray.

I am looking for a way to call Invoke and BeginInvoke methods to pop these Forms without having to refer to another Form or other such Control object. Is that possible? I am able to retrieve an HWND pointer for the "Excel window" that would be hosting my runtime... Is it possible to retrieve an object that has the Invoke and BeginInvoke methods accessible from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) class.

[MethodInvoker Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx)

Comment: Hi, already tried that. First link is what I'm using. It's failing when another workbook of my excel is active, telling me that my control doesnt exist anymore, so can't be parent of my bubbles.. Second link doesn't give any results. I can see the pop up freezing before they entirely show up.